# CSS - How to stop text being pushed down by hidden div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've inherited a codebase and had some responsive tweaks to fix up for our website. I've not had much experience with responsive development outside of simply putting in the bootstrap responsive file (or MVC which complicates matters for me, it's been an enjoyable experience though). The first issue I have is that we have text that usually changes when hovered over.

I disabled that using "hidden-phone" on that div for the changed text and edited the positioning and text size so it displays properly on phone.

The issue is that when the text is hovered over on mobile style devices, the text we want to keep in the same place is being moved.This is the headertext and the masterheader is pushing it down. (the header is also not changing size but I've not had time to look at that properly yet)

The CSS file is roughly 3000 lines long so I'm not positive what should be posted, but I'll put in the offending divs and html which is causing the issue. I'm also more than happy to be critiqued, I've only ever worked on small projects and websites so I'm always open to learning.

```css
@media (max-width: 518px) {
  header#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: -50px;
  }
  #headerText {
    position: relative;
    top: -72px;
    left: 35px;
  }
  h1.masterHeader {
    position: absolute;
  }
  /*a.btn-navbar{
    position:absolute;        
  }*/
  #headerFader.carousel {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="headerText" class="span10 noMargin noPadding">
  <h1 id="masterHeader"><span>text</span>
                                     <span class="carousel slide" id="headerFader">
                                       <span class="carousel-inner">
                                            <span class="item active">text</span>
                                            <span class="item ">text</span>
                                            <span class="item ">text</span>
                                            <span class="item ">text</span>
                                            <span class="item ">text</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </h1>
  <h1 id="takemeback" class="hidden-phone"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>">Take me back home</a></h1>
  <!--Responsive to small devices -->
  <h1 class="deviceLink"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/" accesskey="h">text</a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting **visibility: collapse;**

Comment: a jsfiddle could be nice, also get a look at [CSS : overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)

Comment: overflow / visibility: collapse unfortunately never worked, although adding that in allows the text to pop back up once the text has stopped being hovered over.

Comment: This part works fine: `#headerFader.carousel {display: none;}`, Now if it is showing up again on `#masterHeader` hover and pushing text down, try adding this: `#masterHeader:hover #headerFader.carousel {display: none;}`